# Missing Source and include folder when integrating cmake with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cmake

I am new to CMake and I am trying Integrate CMake with Eclipse.

Below is the example of the file structure that I have.

PROJECT

- build/linux
- build/linux/Release (Should contain the release libraries and files)
- build/linux/Debug   (Should contain the debug version of the files)
- SRC

  1. subProject_1
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 1 for this folder (creating a static library)
  2. subproject_2
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 2 for this folder (creating a static library)
  3. subproject_3
     .cpp (all source files) and CMakeLists.txt 3 for this folder (creating the executable)
- Include

  1. subProject_1
     .h (all the header files)
  2. subProject_2
     .h (all the header files)
  3. subProject_3
     .h (all the header files)

Can you please let me know how would I be able to integrate CMake to Eclipse. I would like to do a in Source build so that I can sub version my code.

I have tried different options of placing the main CMakelist in project folder, project/build/linux folder and so on. I can get the project working but I dont get to see the source folder as well as the include folder on eclipse.

I have tried both 1st and 2nd option specified in http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:Eclipse_UNIX_Tutorial#CMake_with_Eclipse

Comment: How about trying the third option. Install the plugin and that's all !

Comment: You have a problem with the content of your **CMakeList**. I don't know why are you talking about **Eclipse** !!?? it seems you have **two questions**.

Comment: The problem here is just not CMakeList. Its about the integrating the CMake stuff with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually very simple: **from a clean build directory**, you configure cmake using Eclipse as generator (it's easier if you use cmake-gui), and then you **import the build directory** into Eclipse (File, Import, General, Existing Projects into Workspace).